# By or With relating with money

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I just met a minor ugh, to say, uncomfortable situation.

When I was reading a Japanese Manga ( Anime ), the fictional billionair says,

"I have many many money with Yen, Euro, Dollar, but not enough at all!"

So on the premise that the speaker ( writer ) is Japanese, would it be correct
or swappable by **By** instead of **With when you are trying to say you have a lot of money by/with several varieties of currency?**

Thank you so much for your great help in far advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm never entirely certain if I'm translating 'Japlish' correctly, but my best guess is that the idiomatic American English would be ***I have lots of money, in Yen, Euros, and Dollars, but not enough at all!***.

In general, when one specifies a currency for an amount of money, one says that the money is denominated ***in*** the currency. This construction can also be used for amounts invested for profit from companies or commodities, e.g., ***I have thousands of dollars in porkbellies.*** or ***I have several thousand invested in IBM.***.

Comment: **"In general, when one specifies a currency for an amount of money, one says that the money is denominated in the currency."** Great. So the money holder is having the money **in** XXXX currency ( probably the "value" of the currency changes frequently? ) Anyway, thank you.

Comment: The "many many money" sure seems like it came out of a rough translation from the Japanese, though. From もっともっと金 perhaps?

Comment: Uhg, as I described, the "billionair" started studying English so there is no translation. ( with many mistakes lol ) The manga is actually a derivative version of Kaiji [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaiji_%28manga%29), and the billionair is called Hyodo with a nut head. But the series is one of my top recommendations. ^^

Comment: @KentaroTomono - I can think of no context in which one would use ***by*** in connection with currency valuations. Yes, when the currency is not one's own, the value in one's own currency will change, based on current exchange rates.

Comment: @KentaroTomono Got it. I didn't notice that the character was saying this. I suppose the errors were purposely written, or at least it may be difficult to separate the intended one (possibly "many many money" and the unintended ones (possibly "with").

Comment: @user3169 Yes, I think the author is trying to depict the "billionair" a funny guy by him saying "many many" but, the author uses English at various scenes and the latter **with** here is his pure mistake, I thought. That was the reason I asked this question, thank you.